# missing files in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: angular, docker, continuous-integration, pipeline

I'm using bitbucket as a code source control for my angular app.

I'm trying to get to `cd` some path in my project and my pipeline is failed for `No such file or directory.

I added `ls` and I've noticed that not all my project files we're mounted to the image.

That's the `ls` command result:

```
README.md
angular.json
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
some-script.bash
package-lock.json
package.json
src
tsconfig.json
tslint-to-eslint-config.log
tslint_OLD.json
xliffmerge.json
```

Does anyone know where's the rest of my project?? For example, my `e2e` folder?

Comment: are you sure these files/folders were committed to the repository?

Comment: Yes, there must be some configuration that defines which files are mounted and which files aren't